# Open another page using ons-modal

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

How  can i open an another page after onsen ui load this modal 
https://onsen.io/reference/ons-modal.html#example

```
ons.bootstrap();

$(document.body).on("pageinit", '#my-page', function() {
 $("#show-modal", this).click(function() {
  modal.show();
   setTimeout('modal.hide()', 2000);
   });
    });
```

Comment: Just put all page element in ons-model

Comment: Like this? <ons-modal var="modal">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
  <br>
  <br> Please wait.
  <br>Closing in 2 seconds. <ons-template id="sh.html"> page here</ons-template
</ons-modal>

Comment: I want to open an external page. Example: Modal.html  >>> open >>> index.html after the load screen. But i don't know where start

Comment: i've tried  as you told me. But the page opens ,but after 2 seconds back to first page.

Comment: because of setTimeout Method. it becomes hide after 2 seconds remove this from your code. @Leogreen

Comment: i removed the modal.hide >>  setTimeout('modal.hide()', 2000); but now i don't have modal( with my message (Loading the application, please wait), my app just navigate to another page. I'm doing something wrong lol. Do you have an example, or knows one ? Thanks again, your tricks was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

> your view

```
<style>
       .loading {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 45%;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
       }
    </style>

<ons-modal var="modal">
  ...content of your model
</ons-modal>

<ons-navigator>
  <ons-page id="my-page">
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Modal</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <p style="text-align: center">
      <ons-button id="show-modal" modifier="light">Open Modal</ons-button>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv" class="loading ng-hide">
          <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
  <br>
  <br> Please wait.
  <br>Closing in 2 seconds.
    </div>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

> your js file

```
ons.bootstrap();

$(document.body).on("pageinit", '#my-page', function() {
  $("#show-modal", this).click(function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#myDiv')).removeClass('ng-hide');
    setTimeout( function () {angular.element(document.querySelector('#myDiv')).addClass('ng-hide');
                             modal.show();
                                 }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Very useful and helpful. Your result is something different . I'd like to show the modal (please wait  2 seconds) after close the modal and the first page to show a new page. But your result gave me a new possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time